# Unable to forward multiple emails in gmail

Tags: gmail

I have to forward multiple selected mails from my g-mail account. I tried making a filter of the mails and then auto forwarding it to the other email. But it would just forward the future mails. How to forward the past emails?

Comment: Your question belongs here http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this because Gmail does not support multiple mails forwarding.

However you can use OutLook for the same

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use Google Scripts to [auto-forward Gmail messages](http://www.labnol.org/internet/auto-forward-gmail-messages/20665/). You can apply a particular label to these messages that you wish to forward and the script will send them all, one by one, to the specified email adddress.